# sorting python list in recursive manner

Tags: python, python-2.7, sorting

As input I will be getting lists of lists which can up to n-levels and it will vary every time. Suppose, I have a list

```
[[2, 1, 3], 4, [2, 3], 7, 1, [9, [4, 2], 5]]
```

here I want to sort this list and expected output is

```
[1, 4, [2, 3], [1, 2, 3], 7, [5, [2, 4], 9]]
```

Here, first sorting is happening based of elements and then based on sum of elements inside list.

**code:**

```
input_freq = [[2,1,3],4,[2,3],7,1,[9,[4,2],5]]

res = []

def sortFreq(input_freq):
    elements = []
    list_of_elements = []

    for each in input_freq:
        if isinstance(each, list):
            print "list"
            list_of_elements.append(each)
            each.sort()
        else:
            elements.append(each)
            elements.sort()

    print elements
    print list_of_elements

sortFreq(input_freq)
```

expected output:

```
[1, 4, [2, 3], [1, 2, 3], 7, [5, [4, 2], 9]]
```

but my code returns the wrong result:

```
[[1, 2, 3], [2, 3], [5, 9, [4, 2]]]
```

Comment: What is the sum for `[9, [4, 2], 5]`? The sum of the *flattened* elements, so `9 + 4 + 2 + 5 == 20`?

Comment: Well first I don't see you using the sum of the elements of your nested lists at any point, so you're probably at least missing that.

Comment: Secondly, you said "recursive manner" but you implemented an iterative algorithm, are you sure it is what you're aiming for?

Comment: Your input is not a list of lists as you claim. It is a list of <type 'list'>
<type 'int'>
<type 'list'>
<type 'int'>
<type 'int'>
<type 'list'>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to work your way down to the nested levels first, then sort the parent levels as the recursive call returns. I'm going to assume you want to return a new list (and not sort in place):

```
def nested_sort(l):
    def sort_key(e):
        if isinstance(e, list):
            return sum(sort_key(inner) for inner in e)
        return e
    return sorted(
        [nested_sort(e) if isinstance(e, list) else e for e in l],
        key=sort_key)
```

The sort key has to recursively sum nested lists, so this can be kind of expensive if you have many nested levels. In that it may be worth adding a cache based on the identity of the list being summed:

```
def nested_sort(l, _sum_cache=None):
    if _sum_cache is None:
        _sum_cache = {}
    def sort_key(e):
        if isinstance(e, list):
            e_id = id(e)
            if e_id not in _sum_cache:
                _sum_cache[e_id] = sum(sort_key(inner) for inner in e)
            return _sum_cache[e_id]
        return e
    return sorted(
        [nested_sort(e, _sum_cache) if isinstance(e, list) else e for e in l],
        key=sort_key)
```

Demo:

```
>>> nested_sort([[2, 1, 3], 4, [2, 3], 7, 1, [9, [4, 2], 5]])
[1, 4, [2, 3], [1, 2, 3], 7, [5, [2, 4], 9]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that has the benefit of doing every sum only once. It is also quite short:

```
import operator

def sort_lol(lol):
    srtd, sums = zip(*sorted((sort_lol(el) if isinstance(el, list) else (el, el) 
                              for el in lol), key=operator.itemgetter(1)))
    return list(srtd), sum(sums)

lst = [[2,1,3],4,[2,3],7,1,[9,[4,2],5]]
print(sort_lol(lst))

# ([1, 4, [2, 3], [1, 2, 3], 7, [5, [2, 4], 9]], 43)
# note that the function returns the sorted list and the total (43 here)
```

Comment: But I does not return list, it is returning tuples. I dont want to change data structure here.

Comment: @MaheshKaria Oops, fixed.